# Ubuntu 14.04 start error

Tags: unity-greeter

After a few days in a fresh XPSP3/Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot intallation I started to get this error: Executable Path /USR/SBIN/UNITY-GREETER .
This happens every time I start ubuntu and sending a error report doesn't work either, after i close all report windows the system seems apparently normal.
Being the computer illiterate that I am is there a simple enough procedure that could fix this error?
Thank you.